# Display image based on condition in sapui5 table control

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5

I have to display the an image in table column baaed on the value in json model,
For example if model>data = 1 then '1.png' should come in that row ,

The name of the image is coming from json data and extension i have to do hard coding.

Please give me some suggestions , i am new to sapui5.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You could achieve this with a formatter function or expression binding. You should share some code of what you are trying to achieve & where you are stuck at.

Comment: thanks, with formatter the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**XML code**

```
<ObjectStatus icon="{path: 'Status', formatter: '.status'}"/>
```

**This will be the formatter code**

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";
 
    var Formatter = {
 
        status: function(Status) {
            if (Status === "0") {
                return "sap-icon://accept"; // use your png image here 
            } else if (Status === "1") {
                return "sap-icon://decline";
            } else if (Status === "2") {
                return "sap-icon://add";
            }
        }
        
    };
    return Formatter;
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use instead of a formatter some expression language in the attributes of the object in the XML view :

```
<ObjectStatus text="{users-deploy>role-xus}" class="bold"
                    tooltip="{= !${users-deploy>role-xus-authorized} ? ${i18n>roleNotAuthorized} : !${users-deploy>role-xus-exist} ? ${i18n>roleNotExist} : ${i18n>OK}}"
                    state="{= !${users-deploy>role-xus-authorized} ? 'Error' : !${users-deploy>role-xus-exist} ? 'Warning' : 'Success'}"
                    icon="{= ${users-deploy>role-xus} ==='' ? '' :  !${users-deploy>role-xus-authorized} ? 'sap-icon://status-error' : !${users-deploy>role-xus-exist} ? 'sap-icon://status-inactive' : 'sap-icon://status-positive'}" />
```

In my case above I have a model name "users-deploy" and depending on the values of the current object I need the color, icon and tooltip to change. I have find that it works fine this way for me, but it may not be the more optimized way to do it.